# Azure Cloud Domain Controller servicing mobile desktops with Azure Connect?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, dns, cloud

Given the recent updates to Windows Azure, I am wondering if it is possible to create a domain controller and file server in Azure and then connect it to 10 to 20 remote workers using Azure Connect to create a "virtual office".

My primary interest is whether or not a domain controller can exist in the cloud and serve desktops with Active Directory as they roam. This would eliminate the need for on-prem servers for a small business. Active Directory would be used for desktop logins and group policies and potentially to authenticate a hosted file server, SharePoint instance, etc.

I see a lot of posts about domain controllers serving offices over a VPN and replicated Azure domain controllers to on-prem domain controllers, but nothing about whether a domain controller can run in the cloud and serve roaming desktops (presumably with Azure Connect).

Can someone please tell me if this is possible, or otherwise not recommended?

Comment: Hi Jessica, did you ever end up deploying this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible, there are 2 tutorials that can help you with this:

- The first one will help you setup a virtual network: [Create a Virtual Network for Cross-Premises Connectivity](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/cross-premises-connectivity/)
- The second one will help you to install a **new** AD Forest in Windows Azure: [Install a new Active Directory forest in Windows Azure](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/active-directory-forest/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you think in a scenario where there is no central office and maybe 30 remote desktops/laptops that using Azure Connect is an option for communicating with the domain?